# django-admin startproject does not create manage.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a new Django 1.5 project. I just installed Python 2.7.15, created a virtualenv, and installed Django 1.5. I don't have any other version installed.

When I run `python django-admin.py startproject myproject` it creates a new folder:

- `myproject/`

  - `myproject/`

    - `__init__.py`
    - ...

But `manage.py` is missing in the top folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Django _**1.5**_?! Why are you starting a new project with such an ancient version of Django? It hasn't been supported for _years_. If you're getting started with Python and Django I _strongly_ encourage you to upgrade to the latest versions of Django (currently 2.1) and Python (currently 3.7).

Comment: Forced to, there is a dependency on an existing project built on 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I still *strongly* urge you to upgrade whatever you need to upgrade so you can get off of Django 1.5 and onto a supported version, ideally the latest release.

### Solution

I was able to reproduce your problem with `Django==1.5`. For some reason the `lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/project_template/` directory lacks a `manage.py` file.

While I haven't found the bug report, the latest bugfix release in the Django 1.5 lineage, version 1.5.12 (January, 2015), includes `manage.py` as expected. If you must use a 1.5.x version, please use this latest one. It should be compatible.

If you absolutely must use an older version of Django 1.5 that lacks its own `manage.py` you can create the file yourself. Here are its entire contents from my Django 1.5.12 test install:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

You'll have to replace `{{ project_name }}` with your actual project name.

Answer (score 0):

you may also have django installed twice.  I had the same behavior and found that I had installed django twice by following the answer from the below thread:

[django-admin startproject trying to create manage.py twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488571/django-admin-startproject-trying-to-create-manage-py-twice)

Comment: 1- this isn't an answer, it's a wild guess. 2- link only answers are frowned upon. This would be more a comment. (If you don't have enough rep to comment yet, then just wait until you do...)